# Insufficient storage in Galaxy Tab 3 8.0

Tags: internal-storage, storage

My Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 is showing insufficient storage with Applications at 11.6GB.

When I add up all of the application storage requirements I get about 0.75GB.

I supposedly have 49MB available but cannot install a 7MB app. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Well, since 0.75GB is equal to ~750MB, I think that there may be an accidental typo in the question. Or I might be misunderstanding something. Are you saying that the app is a 0.75GB app, or are you saying it's a 7MB app?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your storage menu and also name the app you want to install?